# Where can I find a hand blender like this?

Tags: equipment

My mom uses [this](http://www.rico.in/product-hb-01.html) in India. It is very convenient, has 5 types of detachable blades - some are smooth for mixing, while some sharp for chopping. I haven't been able to find a similar product on amazon.

[image]

Comment: Did you search for "stick mixer"? https://www.google.com.au/search?q=stick+mixer&oq=stick+mixer&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60l5.912j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=0&ie=UTF-8 or http://www.amazon.com/b/ref=dp_brw_link?ie=UTF8&node=289916

Comment: Yes, I couldn't find having chopping blades.

Comment: Is the second one I linked to below what you're looking for?

Comment: Ah yes, thanks! That is as close as you can get. Wish it was less powerful (150W vs 550W) - and thus cheaper - but I'm happy with this. Thanks again!

Comment: You're very welcome. You should be happy with that one, the reviews are very good, it seems to be a quality product. As a matter of fact, that one would replace my mini food processor that just died and I've wanted an immersion blender for some time, so I'm going to get it too :)

Comment: Yes, the reviews are indeed good. I ordered one. :)

Comment: @Jolenealaska Once you have an immersion blender you'll find yourself wondering how you ever survived without one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a hand blender, or [immersion blender](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_ss_i_1_12?url=search-alias%3Dgarden&field-keywords=hand+blenders+immersion&sprefix=hand+blender%2Cgarden%2C314&rh=n%3A1055398%2Ck%3Ahand+blenders+immersion). They're common, Amazon has a bunch of them.

Here's one with [interchangeable blades](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00281QTE0).

Comment: Side note: They're sometimes called "liquidisers" in the UK/Commonwealth. Mind your spelling ;-)

Comment: That looks sooo weird with an S.

Comment: Didn't mean to be disruptive; OP mentioned India and it seemed relevant. Do you prefer "liquidiser" (sans trailing `s`), or "liquidiserz" (in the "can haz" sense)? ;-) A Google search for "[liquidiser](http://www.google.com/search?q=liquidiser)" returns many more useful results for this topic than does "[liquidizer](http://www.google.com/search?q=liquidizer)" (which looks sooo weird; won't you agree?).

Comment: @hoc_age :) Not disruptive at all. I just find the British "ise" odd looking, being more accustomed to the American "ize"