# RPM for milk frothing?

Tags: equipment, coffee, milk, food-processing

So I had one of those American capitalist/consumer moments where I would have liked to have a milk frother handy. But I just can't bring myself to buy such a frivolous single-use additional material possession. So as a compromise I'll get a Dremel tool.

Concerned that I'll need to step down a Dremel tool to work as a milk frother. Has anyone measured the average RPM of a milk frother? Anyone seen a DIY project to attach a gear reduction to a Dremel? Do I actually need *more* RPM?

Loss of torque should not be a big issue, even with whole milk. Half and half, that may be another story.

Comment: I have a couple of dremel tools ... and I don't know that I'd use them for food tasks, because they can kick up so much dust that it gets in the little crevices of the tool.   Unless you're going to use a flex shaft for food only, or the whole tool itself, you then risk the dust from some project falling into your food.  (I use mine for cutting plastic, metal, plaster & drywall; sanding wood, etc.)  You can get a stick blender for less than 1/3 of the cost of a Dremel (and still less than the cost of non-Dremel rotary tool even those with variable speed controls)

Comment: Buy a plastic paint stirring wand from a hardware store, they are designed for drills, but should fit a Dremel chuck. The type that would froth milk have a flat disk with a pizza slice notch cut into one side

Comment: I don't think RPM is important at all, I've seen manual milk frothers.

Comment: I have used an [immersion blender](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/45453/where-can-i-find-a-hand-blender-like-this) for milk frothing; it will help avoid saw-dust in your latte, *and* also makes your new tool a multi-tasker! Also search for other SA articles on immersion blender.

Comment: All great comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Ozeri Deluxe milk frother  claims an rpm of 15000 rpm

[http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00BISKPMG/ref=as_li_ss_tl?ie=UTF8&camp=1789&creative=390957&creativeASIN=B00BISKPMG&linkCode=as2&tag=nmjv-20](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00BISKPMG)

However I have seen in ikea (and pound / dollar stores) a much cheaper option that to me seems much the same

http://www.ikea.com/gb/en/catalog/products/30100041/

Hope this helps